Unity IAP: OnInitialized and OnInitializeFailed not called on some devices
We are using Unity 2022.3.9f1 and Unity IAP 4.11.0. The IAP system works fine in the editor, on iOS, and on our Android test device.
However, our app was rejected during the Google Play Console review because testers couldn't purchase any of our IAP products. After investigating, it seems that neither OnInitialized nor OnInitializeFailed is called during initialization.
Here's our initialization code:
    public void Init(List<BundleShop> listBundle, List<ResourceShop> listResource)
    {
        builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
        for (int i = 0; i < listBundle.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listBundle[i].iapKey))
            {
                builder.AddProduct(listBundle[i].iapKey, ProductType.Consumable);
                listIapInfo.Add(new IapInfo(listBundle[i].shopId, listBundle[i].iapKey, false));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listResource.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listResource[i].iapKey))
            {
                builder.AddProduct(listResource[i].iapKey, ProductType.Consumable);
                listIapInfo.Add(new IapInfo(listResource[i].shopId, listResource[i].iapKey, true));
            }
        }
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        storeController = controller;
        storeExtension = extensions;
        appleExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();
        googleExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<IGooglePlayStoreExtensions>();
        isReady = true;
        Packet.instance.SendLogsIapStatus("OnInitialized");
    }

    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error, string message)
    {
        PopupMessage.instance.ShowPopupMessage("IAP: OnInitialized FAIL => " + error + " => " + message, "ERROR");
        Packet.instance.SendLogsIapStatus("OnInitializeFailed", "message", message);
    }

    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        PopupMessage.instance.ShowPopupMessage("IAP: OnInitialized FAIL NO Message => " + error, "ERROR");
        Packet.instance.SendLogsIapStatus("OnInitializeFailed", "no message");
    }

We Have Tried:

Running the APK on an emulator without signing into the Google API
Running an unsigned APK on an Android device
Running a signed APK on an Android device
In all cases, either OnInitialized or OnInitializeFailed is called.

Could any settings in the Google Play Console be causing this issue? Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?
